# I'm having to invalidate cache and restart android studio multiple times to get log functionality. Why?

Tags: android-studio

I heavily depend on Logcat for debugging my code, as do most of you. However, I'm able to generate logs only for about 3 times in a given session. The emulator works fine and I can still reinstall the app with changed functionality and all. But to get the Logcat working, I need to invalidate cache and restart Android Studio multiple times in a day. The restart takes about 5-10 minutes which is wasted time.

Does my Studio have some issues and/or is there any alternative?

Comment: What is the version of your android studio and what do you see when logcat doesn't work? Have you tried running logcat through adb?

Comment: Version is 3.6.3. I don't understand what the second part means.

Comment: Since you installed Android Studio, you are supposed to also have installed adb, which is [Android Debug Bridge](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb). I would try to run logcat through the adb command inside the terminal. Run ```adb logcat```.